# Sorting algorithms for List,set,Map ,Tree and graph

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Most of sorting algorithms(Insertion Sort,Bubble Sort,Quick Sort, Merge sort,etc) has explained with list. Don't we have specific sorting algorithms for Map,Graph,Tree?

Comment: http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms is your answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but uncommon.

If you want a sorted tree, you usually build it in sorted order. It is fairly common to rearrange nodes/branches in a tree. If you're building a binary search tree, you might rearrange nodes to keep it balanced. If you're working with an abstract syntax tree in a compiler, you might rearrange nodes to optimize computation.

A map is a more abstract structure that could be implemented with a binary search tree, a skip list, a B-tree, a hash table, etc. Most of these pre-suppose some specific order of the contents.

A graph is basically a generalization of a tree. It's certainly possible to apply some types of sorting to a graph (e.g., a topological sort on a graph is pretty routine). You typically use a graph if the data has some structure of its own, and reducing it to an ordered sequence would lose a great deal of the data in the graph.

For example, a typical use of a graph might be to represent train stations as nodes, and train connections between those stations as arcs in the graph. You could then walk the graph to find ways to travel from one city to another via those rail connections.

It could make sense to extract a subset of data from the graph (e.g., names of cities) and sort that data into a sequence, such as getting a list of departures from from a particular station, ordered by departure time, and listing the destination of each. You might also want to produce a sorted list of (major) destinations, and departure times to take for each.

These would really be extracting data, then sorting that extracted data though, not sorting the graph itself. The whole reason (or most of the reason, anyway) the graph is built as a graph in the first place is because the data it contains won't easily reduce to a single list in one specific order.

Comment: You mean that Set, Tree, Map, Graph all mostly created in a structured way,so its uncommon to sort

Comment: More or less, anyway, yes.